# What happens if you give a devil axe to the lumberjack in his side quest?

Tags: fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia

In Chapter 3 of Celica's path, [in the lumberjack sidequest](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/fire-emblem-echoes-side-quest-guide/), the lumberjack asks you to give him an axe so I gave him an ordinary axe. Later on, however, I found a devil axe.

Would something different have happened if I gave him the devil axe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Serene's Forest](https://serenesforest.net/fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia/miscellaneous/sub-quests/), the reward for that Sub Quest will be a Bear Carving regardless of what you give the lumberjack. Since this is the case, it's best to give him the lowest quality item. In this case, that would be the axe you gave him.